# React-Native UI-Kitten Modal triggers "update during an existing state transition" warning everytime

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I've recentçy started coding in react-native, after a couple years of "normal" ReactJS for the web, so I'm using the same "techniques" I've used in like forever, but it doesn't seem to work the same way.

I have this modal, imported from UI-Kitten 5:

```
        <Modal visible={this.state.deviceFoundVisible} backdropStyle={StyleConnectScreen.backdrop}>
          <Card
            appearance={'filled'}
            status={'success'}
            header={(props) => (
              <Layout style={StyleConnectScreen.modal_header}>
                <Text category={'h3'}>{translate('device_found')}</Text>
              </Layout>
            )}
            footer={(props) => (
              <Layout style={StyleConnectScreen.layout_modal_buttons} level={'2'}>
                <Button style={StyleConnectScreen.button_modal} onPress={this.onDeviceFoundCancelHandler}>
                  <Text>{translate('cancel')}</Text>
                </Button>
                <Button status={'success'} style={StyleConnectScreen.button_modal} onPress={this.onDeviceFoundConfirmHandler}>
                  <Text>{translate('confirm')}</Text>
                </Button>
              </Layout>
            )}
          >
            <Layout style={StyleConnectScreen.modal_content}>
              <Text category={'h6'}>{translate('connect_to_device')}: </Text>
              <Text style={{fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular'}} category={'h5'}>{(this.state.foundDevice !== null ? this.state.foundDevice.name : '')}</Text>
            </Layout>
          </Card>
        </Modal>
```

First of all, I have a huge preference for Class Components, maybe because I used React since the 0.xx versions. Am I wrong for still using these?
But the real issue is, when I change the state of ***this.state.deviceFoundVisible*** the modal appears, but always triggers a warning:

```
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
```

This value is updated when a BLE device is found, which is done by Promises. Is the async nature of the promises triggering this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: might be necessary to see more of your component code. specifically how you are setting the deviceFoundVisible.

Comment: That code is inside  an async/await function that is listening for any device. I found that moving the block I showed above out of a <Consumer> block makes it go away, most of the times. So far my solution was to use React-Native's modals, seem to work without any errors so far